Variable Angle Cone
Does anyone know of a mechanism that can change the angle of a 3D cone? Similarly to how a camera shutter changes the diameter of the inner circle, it needs to be controlled by twisting or pushing a rod or other mechanical device that can be operated with a servo motor. It doesn't need to be a perfect cone, but it must be made out of rigid parts. Thanks for your help!


Rigid enough to do what? Have you used an umbrella?

You need to upload the image using the Image button or Ctrl-G. The link you've provided gives a 404 error.

Can you provide drawings of the "cone" in the two end positions, giving some dimensions, the thickness of the leaves relative to their height and width, the number of leaves, how much the tip of the cone is truncated and where the extra material is to go when in the collapsed position. e.g., I suspect that in the closed position the excess material has to project tangentially from the cone given that you've said it has to be rigid.

Do you require rigidity at every stage or just at the 2 extreme stages?

Can the cone have thickness about the perimeter/surface? I'm envisioning a series of triangular shapes with a pivot at the pointed end of the triangle and another at the center of the triangle base. As each triangle is rotated, perhaps joined to the adjacent triangle, the perimeter of the base of the cone will contract. If one cannot have thickness, disregard. If one can have thickness, I'll create an answer with a diagram/drawing.
